# Group/Sort SQL by two columns or more. Most common values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I am trying to figure out the most occurring values within a table in groups.
This is for SQL

Headers: Part, location, PartDesc

```
A | 2 | Part A
A | 2 | Part A
A | 2 | Part A
A | 1 | Part A
A | 1 | Part A
B | 1 | Part B
B | 2 | Part B
```

So the output needs to show

Headers: Part, Location, PartDesc, Occurrence

```
A | 2 | Part A | 3
A | 1 | Part A | 2 
B | 1 | Part B | 1
B | 2 | Part B | 1
```

So far I have

```
Select Part, count(*) as occurrence
from
table1
group by Part
order by count(*desc)
```

Hope this is clear. Many thanks

Comment: Pick a database. mysql <> sql server <> sqlite.

Comment: Just add location and PartDesc to the select list and to the group by clause.

Comment: Most likely this is MySQL since OP would have gotten an error with that incomplete `GROUP BY` in any other RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting close:

```
SELECT Part, Location, PartDesc, count(*) as Occurrence
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Part, Location, PartDesc
ORDER BY Occurence
```

You want to put every field that you are grouping on, in the `GROUP BY` section. Really this is any field that you aren't aggregating with a `Max()`, `Sum()` or something like that. The `ORDER BY` can also take multiple fields if you want a more complex sort.

Comment: Ah I see, works perfect thanks man. Was nearly there a little further on. :)